# How would I get my program to only output whether or not it is on space 49.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I get my program to only output that it is on square 49 and not square 54 etc. e.g I'm on number 54 but I only want the program to tell me I'm on space 49.

```
if dice1!=dice2:
        print("You are now on space", position+total)
        position=total+position
    if position>=49:
        print("You are on space 49")
        if position<=0:
            print("You are on square 0")
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want it to lie to you, or to only tell you your position if position equals 49?

Comment: You need to reach 49 to finish the game so if I get 54 it is pointless showing me this so how would I get it to just tell me I'm on space 49

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code example. And while you're doing that please add the values for `dice1`, `dice2`, `total` and `position` to your question.

Comment: Am I missing something? Just change `>=` to `==` to match the number exactly.

Comment: `if position <= 0:` can never be true, since it's inside the `if position >= 49:` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
if position >= 49: #if the value is 54, this would default to 49. 
    print('You are on space 49, game over!')
else:
    break
```

Otherwise:

`if position == 49: #this would require the position to exactly equal an integer of 49. 
     print('You are on space 49, game over!')`